# Split Overlapping Dates in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split overlapping dates from a table which have multiple overlapping Start date and End Date.

```
Ex : 
Start Date                      Start Date
2023-02-01 00:00:00.000     2023-02-17 00:00:00.000
2023-02-15  00:00:00.000    2023-02-20 00:00:00.000
2023-02-18  00:00:00.000    2023-02-22 00:00:00.000
2023-02-23 00:00:00.000     2023-02-25 00:00:00.000
2023-02-26 00:00:00.000     2023-03-06 00:00:00.000
```

Expected Ouput:

```
 2023-02-01 00:00:00.000    2023-02-17 00:00:00.000
2023-02-18  00:00:00.000    2023-02-22 00:00:00.000
2023-02-23 00:00:00.000     2023-02-25 00:00:00.000
2023-02-26 00:00:00.000     2023-03-06 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Are you simply looking for a way to make sure there is no overlap between rows? Or you are looking for a speicifc way to split/merge the rows? The current exepcted output seems more a merge instead of a split? why should the 2nd row disappear? another way of split could be [2023-02-01,2023-02-15][2023-02-15,2023-02-17][2023-02-18,2023-02-20][2023-02-21,2023-02-22][2023-023-23,2023-02-25][2023-02-26,20223-03-06]

Comment: Yes its should not Overlap with another date in a table.

Comment: To be specific here, are you expecting the output exactly as you shown in the example output (4 rows with no overlap)? or are you good as long as there is no overlap in the output?  There are ways to generate output without overlap, but it might not be exactly as what you show in the example output.

Comment: good as long as there is no overlap in the output. Please provide any input

Answer (score 0):

To generate the output without overlapping dates, you can use SQL [window functoin](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) and some math tricks to achieve that in a few steps.

Step 1. Use window function and sort the records by start_date, generate a end_date column to be max_end_date we see so far.

Step 2. Use window function on top of Step 1 result and sort the records by start_date again, this time, generate a column called expected_start, which should be `last seen max end date + 1`

Step 3. filter any row that `expected_start>= max_end_date`, set expected_start as new start date and max_end_date so far as end_date.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ecb1e/6):

```
with input_with_max_end AS (
select
    start_date,
    end_date,
    max(end_date) over (order by start_date) as max_end_based_on_start
from input_table
),
input_with_expected_start AS (
select
    start_date,
    end_date,
    max_end_based_on_start,
    dateadd(day,1, lag(max_end_based_on_start) over (order by start_date)) as expected_start
from
    input_with_max_end
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(expected_start, start_date) as start_date,
    max_end_based_on_start as end_date
from
    input_with_expected_start
where
    COALESCE(expected_start, start_date) < max_end_based_on_start
```

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-01T00:00:00Z | 2023-02-17T00:00:00Z |
| 2023-02-18T00:00:00Z | 2023-02-20T00:00:00Z |
| 2023-02-21T00:00:00Z | 2023-02-22T00:00:00Z |
| 2023-02-23T00:00:00Z | 2023-02-25T00:00:00Z |
| 2023-02-26T00:00:00Z | 2023-03-06T00:00:00Z |